# How to install RPM files in Tails OS

Tags: software-installation, yum, rpm, dnf, tails-os

I would like to use Skype on Tails 4.7 running on a live USB flash drive. I downloaded the RPM file and looked up the installation procedure, but none of `rpm`, `yum`, and `dnf` works ("command not found"). What shall I do? Also, does Tails and the bundled Tor browser allow camera and microphone access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tails, The Amnesic Incognito Live System, is based on Debian.  It would not use `rpm`s but instead uses `deb`s managed by `dpkg`.

[The recommended method to install new software into Tails is to use the Synaptic Package Manager](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/additional_software/index.en.html), though it would appear that Skype has not been packaged by Debian and I am not aware of the best way to install that software.